# DataGridView cells not editable when using an outside thread call

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I'm not able to edit my datagridview cells when a number of identical calls takes place on another thread. Here's the situation:

- Dataset table is created in the main window
- The program receives in files and processes them on a background thread in class `TorrentBuilder : BackgroundWorker` creating an array objects of another class `Torrent`
- My program receives those objects from the BW result and adds them into the dataset

The above happens either on my main window thread or in another thread:

I have a separate thread watching a folder for files to come in, and when they do come in, they proceed to call `TorrentBuilder.RunWorkerAsynch()` from that thread, receive the result, and call an outside class that adds the `Torrent` objects into the table.

When the files are received by the latter thread, the datagridview isn't editable. All of the values come up properly into the datagridview, but when I click on a cell to edit it: **I can write letters and everything, but when I click out of it, it immediately reverts back to its original value. If I restart the program, I can edit the same cells just fine.**

If the values are freshly added from the main window thread, I can edit the cells just fine.

The outside thread is called from my main window thread, and sits there in the background. I don't believe it to be ReadOnly because I would have gotten an exception.

Here's some code:

**From my main window class:**

```
private void dataGridView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
      if (Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".zip") || Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".rar"))
      {
          foreach (string unzipped in dh.UnzipFile(file))
          al.Add(unzipped);
      }
      else if (Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".torrent"))
      {
          al.Add(file);
      }
    }

dataGridViewProgressBar.Visible = true;
tb.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(tb_DragDropCompleted);
tb.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(tb_DragDropProgress);
tb.RunWorkerAsync()
}

void tb_DragDropCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   data.AddTorrents((Torrent[])e.Result);
   builder.Dispose();
   dh.MoveProcessedFiles(data);
   dataGridViewProgressBar.Visible = false; 
}
```

**From my outside Thread**

```
while (autocheck)
{
   if (torrentFiles != null)
   {
     builder.RunWorkerAsync(torrentFiles);
     while (builder.IsBusy)
     Thread.Sleep(500);
   }
}
void builder_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      data.AddTorrents((Torrent[])e.Result);
      builder.Dispose();
      dh.MoveProcessedFiles(xml);
      data.Save(); //Save just does an `AcceptChanges()` and saves to a XML file
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to one I've experienced -- and asked about on SO:

[DataGridView -- Simultaneous input and output -- Is this a bug in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942782/datagridview-simultaneous-input-and-output-is-this-a-bug-in-datagridview)

I hope you have more luck than me in coming up with a good solution.

Comment: Ah geez, and I was hoping for a simple solution. :] Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A sloppy solution for sure, but the only way I could make my cells editable again was to do a complete refresh.

```
private void DataGridViewCompleteRefresh()
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = null;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            dataGridView.DataSource = data.table;
            dataGridView.Columns["Site Origin"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Year"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Bitrate"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Release Format"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Bit Format"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Handled"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["Error"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Columns["File Path"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView.Update();
            dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```